# Azure AutomationAccount DSC scripts debug

Tags: azure, dsc

I am running a DSC script from an Azure automation account to configure Windows VMs.  It downloads files from a storage account in Azure to hosts for more configurations.  If I hardcode the storage SAS token, it works fine.  But I would like to get the SAS token in the DSC script.  I use managed identity of the Automation account and assigned proper IAM access in storage account.  I am able to get the SAS token in a test runbook script, but not in DSC script.

I got the main part of the code from
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/enable-managed-identity-for-automation

The error I am getting indicates that the SAS token is not generated correctly, but I can't find a way to see what the error msgs are from this part of the code in DSC when it executed.

any help/suggestion is appreciated!

```
Configuration DSCtest {
Import-DscResource -ModuleName 'PSDesiredStateConfiguration'

$resource= "?resource=https://management.azure.com/" 
$url = $env:IDENTITY_ENDPOINT + $resource 
$Headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]" 
$Headers.Add("X-IDENTITY-HEADER", $env:IDENTITY_HEADER) 
$Headers.Add("Metadata", "True") 
$accessToken = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method 'GET' -Headers $Headers
$Atoken = $accessToken.access_token
Write-Output $Atoken

$toDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(4).toString("yyyy-MM-ddT00:00:00Z")
$params = @{canonicalizedResource="/file/storageacnt/exec";signedResource="c";signedPermission="rcw";signedProtocol="https";signedExpiry=$toDate}
$jsonParams = $params | ConvertTo-Json

$sasResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/rg-xxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/storageaccnt/listServiceSas/?api-version=2017-06-01 -Method POST -Body $jsonParams -Headers @{Authorization="Bearer $Atoken"} -UseBasicParsing 

$sasContent = $sasResponse.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
$sasCred = $sasContent.serviceSasToken

write-host $sasCred  

$sasToken = "?$sasCred"

Node LocalHost {
....
```

Comment: In the docs I only see use of an Automation Account Managed Identity used in the context of automation runbooks/workflows. I don't see any mention of it in DSC docs. [These docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-dsc-diagnostics) do describe ways of setting up logging for state configuration

Comment: @RoderickBant, yes the doc I provided is about runbooks, but I don't see any reason why it would not work in DSC unless I am wrong about it.  I followed the steps and enabled the diagnostics for DSC, but it only reports the DSC statuses and other information about the jobs, not the error logs.